# Cassandra 'nodetool repair -pr' taking way too much time

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1, nodetool

I am running a cluster with *1 datacenter (10 nodes)* and *Cassandra 2.1.7* installed on each. We are using *SimpleStretegy* (old mistake).

The situation is, I have not run any *nodetool repair* since begining, and now there is data of about 200 GB with 3 RF.

As running *full repair* or *incremental repair* is same at this point. So I have tried to run *full repair*. But this result in coordinator node down.

So I end up running full partition ranges repair (*nodetool repair -pr*) on each node one at a time. But this is taking way too much time (15+ hrs for each node, hence weeks for all nodes).

Am I doing this wrong, or this is supposed to happen? Or this is a version problem?

In future, if I run full repair again after finishing this, would this take weeks as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since full repair is mainly affected by data size, it should take same amount of time.

I suggest moving to incremental repairs, this should save your time and resources.

Here's a article about how to do this in 2.1:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesMigration.html

Comment: Would incremental repair be sufficient for overall health of the cluster? Can this eliminate the need for full repair?

Comment: Sure, that's what it suppose to solve. It also a default type of repair in later versions.

Answer (score 1):

If your date size too big, you can use Sub-range repair, it's smiliar to repair pr but it's focus in sub range.

For more explain : 
https://www.pythian.com/blog/effective-anti-entropy-repair-cassandra